# Compressed file syntax that is supported across all PowerShell versions

Tags: powershell, batch-file

May I know what syntax can be used across all PowerShell version for compressing files?

I noticed that compressed file syntax for v1 and v5 are completely different.

- v5: `Compress-Archive`
- v1: `[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory`

Note: Currently using Windows 7 but soon will be upgrading to Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell v5 supports using v1 commands in it. So this is a v1 code:

```
$source = "C:\fso"

$destination = "C:\fso1\FSO_Backup.zip"

 If(Test-path $destination) {Remove-item $destination}

Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"

[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($Source, $destination)
```

**Note**

PowerShell will throw error if there's already compressed file at `$destination`, so I am checking the path and delete if there's already file.

Look [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-create-zip-archive-of-folder/) for further information.

Comment: tried 'addtype -assemblyName', addtype -path c:\\','system.io.compression.compressionlevel' still not working. No ability to install external 7z and update to powershell 5

Comment: did you copy the code and run it in Powershell v1/v5 and it didn't work? and what do you mean install external 7z and update to ps 5?

Comment: After exploring i only can zip using external party zip tool which is 7z in my personal station but i dont have the ability to change or modified it for work purpose. Dont even said about upgrade to powershell version 5.

Comment: 7zip has a tool named 7z.exe located inside 7zip install directory. You can use it from powershell as follows: 7z.exe a -tzip -y "sample.7z" "<path>"

Comment: where (sample.7z) is the output zipped file, and <path> is the path to the folder or file you want to archive.